# set kendo form validation to false

Tags: jquery, validation, kendo-ui

I have an HTML form with an textbox in it. The user can type email address in the textbox. When ever the user types wrong mail id i want to make the form validation to false.
For form validation am using Kendo Validator, but am unable to manually set the form validation to false .

The email address validation is done via regrex and thats working fine.

Comment: Post some of the code you tried please, otherwise it's impossible to help

Comment: At least we need to see your kendo validator code and the html